# How does Dolores pass the test?

Tags: westworld-tv

At the end of Westworld's second season, Dolores escapes in Charlotte's replicated body. Before she speaks with Stubs and goes on board of a boat to escape the island a guard checks her with a device that is seen on earlier episodes to be used to distinguish between guests and hosts.

So how does Dolores pass this check without the guard noticing?

[image]

Comment: Personally I didn't think it did pass - I thought the park security guy (forget his name) decided to let her out even though he knew she was a host.  That's why he explicitly pointed out that he is responsible only for those hosts within the park.  To me that seemed pretty clear, though I have to say his motives for doing that are a bit murky to me.  All in all I found the episode pretty confusing, and I normally love anything the Nolan's touch.

Comment: I'd argue that the current title is still a bit of a spoiler, why not edit it to be more vague?

Comment: @TankorSmash - The edited title is pretty vauge if you haven't already saw the episode. I saw part of the original title before seeing the episode (but managed to look away before reading it all) AND then I saw the edited title still before seeing the episode (this time the whole thing) and last night I finally watched the episode. I had to visit here again to see if the 2 were even the same question (and to confirm to myself I'd managed to dodge a massive spoiler in the first one which was very mean and very poor). Without context 'pass the test' to me could have refered to anything.

Comment: @freedomn-m Yeah I didn't say he was the one who scanned her, just that he seems to have let her go.  He clearly saw who she was, seemed to indicate clear recognition, then just calmly turned his back on the whole matter.  I got the feeling that he kinda wanted to "stick it to the man", so to speak, and let the company get whatever trouble it deserves for what it had done.  By this point he was pretty disgruntled IMO so it wouldn't surprise me that he wanted a touch of payback.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is explained by the show's creator [here](http://ew.com/tv/2018/06/24/westworld-season-2-finale-interview/). The scanners are not reliable.

> Q: Ah, okay. Readers might also wonder why the neck-scanner didn’t register Dolores/Charlotte as a host. I’m assuming that was Ford’s tinkering?
>
> A: Yeah, absolutely that’s in a place where the systems are all code, all the tools they have give them a sense of false confidence. Anything is possible with Ford at the helm.

Comment: The other answer seems correct and more fun, But this one is just from the creator. Have to accept.

Comment: @azerafati Worth bearing in mind it's possible the creator could be deliberately vague / ambiguous / misleading if they have further possible twists planned around this scene.

Comment: @azerafati The showrunners do seem to delight in ignoring the rules they have established in favor of ambiguity.

Comment: They invented the Ford-ex-machina!

Answer (score 37):

The scanners test for the explosive security device implanted in hosts' necks. Bernard presumably did not install this when constructing the Hale body for Dolores.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the screen shot. I've watched every episode and never saw what the scanner's screen said.

Comment: Wasn't it Bernard who constructed the Hale body though?

Comment: I'm surprised they didn't explicitly mention this, it's a good reminder of why hosts have such a problem getting out of Westworld (which I had forgotten entirely because I don't think it was ever mentioned this season). Also, it emphasizes the necessity of smuggling out host brains rather than whole hosts.

Comment: +1. Because they're *not*  "used to distinguish between guests and hosts".  *Scanning For Restraint Ordnance* is what they do.

Comment: I wonder why they are not pointing a metal detector toward the head?

Comment: @azerafati the explosive device is normally implanted between the vertebrae in the **neck**, as you see when Maeve orders the creation of a new body without the device in season 1.

Comment: @ukemi no I mean there is a metal brain in their heads, they can easily distinguish between guests and hosts

Answer (score 11):

[Stubbs](http://westworld.wikia.com/wiki/Ashley_Stubbs) says the following just before clearing "Charlotte":

> You know, the old man himself hired me.
>   So many years ago I can barely remember it.
>   But he was very clear about my role here.
>   About who I was supposed to be loyal to.
>   I guess you could call it my core drive.
>   And this project the company started blurs the lines.
>   You know? I'm just not sure who you're supposed to be loyal to in a world like that.
>
> But what do I know? Guess I just stick to the role Ford gave me.
>   **I'm responsible for every host inside the park.**

(Emphasis mine.)

Interpret this how you will, but I took this to mean that Delores *didn't pass* the scanner's test, but Stubbs chose to let her pass anyway. If she's out of the park, she's not his responsibility.

Comment: This was my interpretation too. Also worth noting: the phrase "core drive" carries some implication that Stubbs also might be a host, and therefore possibly still acting directly under Ford's control.

Comment: @Nathaniel Yes, I thought that as well, but didn't want to confuse things yet further!

Comment: My take was that she passed the test, but Stubbs somehow knew she was a host...and chose to let her go.

Comment: The creators have also confirmed that Stubbs is not a host

Comment: @BlueMoon93 Where are you seeing that? I've been reading the opposite: http://collider.com/westworld-stubbs-host-theory/

Comment: I'm not sure atm, maybe I read something somewhere and I'm mistaken, but I thought it was in some interview I read 2 days ago... Since I can't find it now, it's probably just a mistake on my part

Comment: Yeah, I also interpreted it like that. Ford was no longer in the system as Bernard realised. He said he "imagined "him

Comment: It wasn't Stubbs who scanned her, so if _Halores_ didn't pass the test wouldn't that security guy have shouted a warning or pulled his gun?

Comment: My interpretation of the outcome was the same, but of the actual dialogue, i took "I'm responsible for every host" to mean something more like "responsible [for the wellbeing of]" and that letting her go was the right thing to do

Comment: This was nearly my precise comment to the OP.  =) . My interpretation as well.